# Issues with VBA constants

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

Earlier today I had a run time error 448 (named object not found) with the following code, written in Excel:

```
Sub PPTextbox()

Dim PowerPointApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim myPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim mySlide As Object
Dim DestinationPPT As String

Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
DestinationPPT = "H:\VBA\Kapitalanlageplanung - Präsentationen\Monatsbericht\MonatsberichtTemplate.pptm"
Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open(DestinationPPT)
Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(myPresentation.Slides.Count + 1, 12)

mySlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(Type:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=100, Top:=100, Width:=200, Height:=50).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Test Box"

End Sub
```

Turns out, the issue was `Type:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal`, replacing it with a simple `1` did the trick.

[This comment I found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18507192/10602575) gave me the solution. I know now I used late-binding by declaring `mySlide` as an Object. I know now it is inefficient and obviously can lead to some problems like I encountered. But why? Is there some logic behind it or do I just have to accept that "some of VBA constants are not recognised and they are treated as variables" when late-binding? Also, is that a  random occurrence because the exact same code worked earlier?

Comment: As long as you have a reference set to the library that contains the enum values (in this case the Office library) you shouldn't have an issue. If you don't, then you need to declare the constants yourself, or use literal values. Also, just FYI, late binding has nothing to do with whether or not you have a reference set, other than the fact that you have to late bind if you *don't* have a reference.

Comment: Further to Rory's comment, if `msoTextOrientationHorizontal` isn't 'known' to Excel, and Option Explicit is not used, then Excel will just assume that is a variable name and default to zero. So in that case, what you're trying to run if you don't set it up first, is `msoTextOrientationHorizontal = 0`.

Comment: Are you sure that you're Late Binding?  I would not expect `Dim PowerPointApp As PowerPoint.Application` to work unless you were Early Binding (because otherwise, how would Excel know what the `PowerPoint` object was?)  Also, `msoTextOrientationHorizontal` is part of the `MsoTextOrientation` Enum natively available in Excel, so should not have needed replacing with `1`

Comment: @Rory Do you mean Tools < References < MS PowerPoint 15. Object Library? I've got that checked, but it's still not working, meaning `msoTextOrientationHorizontal` and other constants aren't recognized.

Comment: @CLR So how do I make it known. PowerPoint object library is checked under references and I've tried turning it off and on again and also restarted Excel. And it seems to be the same for every VBA constant

Comment: @Alex Do you have the "Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library" ticked under your References too?  That's the shared MSO library, which includes `MsoTextOrientation`

Comment: Apologies, I've assumed it was a PowerPoint constant, but it's not. With no PP references bound, `?msoTextOrientationHorizontal` produces `1` so I'm unsure how that is the problem. As @Chronocidal states, you need Microsoft Office xx.0 Object Library ticked.

Comment: No, I mean the Microsoft Office library reference for your version.

Comment: @Chronocidal Not at all, I don't really know what I'm talking about. But thanks for further explaining it (sometimes stating something wrong seems to be the best way to learn). It seems these constants aren't being recognized for some reason.

Comment: @Chronocidal @Rory Nope, thank you. This gets the code above to work, however a different piece of code now gives me a "Variable not defined" for the line `Workbook1.Close (SaveChanges = False)`

Comment: Assuming `Workbook1` is a declared variable, your error is in the argument you're using - it should read `Workbook1.Close SaveChanges:=False` as it's a named argument.

Comment: @Rory Ok, so this works. Why exactly is `Workbook1.Close (SaveChanges = False)` wrong?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Yeah, I realized that now

Comment: the syntax for named arguments uses the `:=` operator: `SageChanges:=False`

Comment: It's wrong because what you entered is actually an expression meaning "is the variable `SaveChanges` equal to False?". Unless you have actually declared a variable by that name, that expression will always evaluate to `True` (cf here: http://excelmatters.com/2013/10/03/whats-in-a-colon/)

Comment: @Rory Thanks a lot for taking the time to explain all this to me! I gotta read up on some of the really basic stuff and also have to go through my code and check it for similar mistakes.

Answer (score 4):

I always use late-binding so that my code will run on other PCs without activating the dependencies. Portability is critical. I like to then define the constants that would be set by early binding manually.

```vb
Const msoTextOrientationHorizontal As Integer = 1    

Sub PPTextbox() 
    Dim PowerPointApp As Object
    Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    Dim DestinationPPT As String
    DestinationPPT = "H:\VBA\Kapitalanlageplanung - Präsentationen\Monatsbericht\MonatsberichtTemplate.pptm"
    Dim myPresentation As Object
    Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open(DestinationPPT)
    Dim mySlide As Object
    Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(myPresentation.Slides.Count + 1, 12)

    mySlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(Type:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=100, Top:=100, Width:=200, Height:=50).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Test Box" 
End Sub
```